# Automate SVN revision comparisons

Tags: ruby, svn, automation, diff, beyondcompare3

I was doing a lot of comparisons between different SVN revisions and different pipelines using Beyond Compare, and was wondering if it is possible to write a Ruby script or use another tool that can automate the process that scans an SVN log and generates a report of the diffs between two given revisions?

Comment: `svn diff` doesn't work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [Stack Overflow Newbie Manual](http://grahn.us/projects/stack-overflow.php?name=Yazhen%20Alex%20Liu). It will help your questions get answers.

Comment: Yes, it's fairly easy to write a script to call `svn log` and `svn diff` and save the output. You could also use the various language bindings and libraries for Subversion from your scripting/programming language of choice, instead of wrapping the client. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Explain in greater details what you want to do with the results, so why that comparison has "value" for you. And explain why ruby is here mentioned, is it the scripting language you know best? The is no easy integration of Subversion into Ruby, see [Using the API](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.developer.usingapi.html).